# Cannot display background-image

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, background-image

I have the following `div`:

```
<div class="col-lg-5 ml-lg-auto">                            
    <div class="image-container">
        <img class="table-img" src="/img/home.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

essentially I would like to display a background-image in `.image-container`, so I have created the following class:

```
.image-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/car.png);
}
```

the folder structure looks like this:

```
/ source
    / img
    / css
```

when I inspect `.image-container` I get the correct url and when I open this in a new window I can see the file, also if I specificy here `background-image: url('https://somesite.com/image.png');` the image in the container is displayed, so seems like a relative url issue but I can't see the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the proble is the `height` setting of `.image-container`: It's 100%, but 100% of what? If the parent container doesn't have a defined height, and if the div itself has no contents, its height will result being 0, so you won't see anything. To try if that applies, set `height` to a fixed pixel value. If you then see the background image, the problem is definitely the `height` setting.

Comment: The problem can't be the `height` 'cause if I load an image from an internet site like this: `background-image: url('https://somesite.com/image.png');` all works well

Comment: Ok, I found the problem was the image which have a resolution of 6000x4500